# Efficient way to fill an array with its own indices in Rebol3

Tags: arrays, random, rebol3

What's a neat one-liner to fill an array (of given possibly dynamic size) with its own indices?

I was trying this:

```
data: copy {}
repeat tilenum totaltiles [ append data rejoin [tilenum " "] ]
```

...and then looking to convert it into an array, but there must be a more Rebolish way of doing such a thing, I think.

My end goal is actually to then randomize the order of the array's contents, which I think would be the output of `random myarrayhere`, but perhaps there's even a way to do all of this in one fell swoop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want random array (**block!**) why not start with block instead of string in the first place?

```
>> random array/initial length: 10 does [-- length]
== [3 10 7 9 2 5 8 6 1 4]
```

Comment: Starting with a block is exactly what I was looking for, except I didn't realize you could use `does` as an argument to `array/initial`, which makes total sense now that I see it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option to show you a few more Rebol tricks. `collect` and `keep` are very cool in this setting.

```
random collect [ repeat tilenum 10 [ keep tilenum ] ]
```

I updated my first answer to use `repeat` as suggested by @rebolek as I agree that the `for` syntax is less than perfect.

If you want really random numbers and don't mind the risk of a repeated number there is more concise option using the `loop` construct

```
collect [ loop 10 [ keep random 100 ] ]
```

Comment: COLLECT/KEEP is nice trick and you can use `repeat tilenum 10 [...]` - I really don't like FOR :)

Comment: Super, I like this syntax, but the accept goes to @rebolek solely for being first.